# pyautogui: keep trying until find image

Tags: python, pyautogui

How to do a search for an image in a specific place on the screen, in a continuous search with a limit of 'x' of seconds, until the image is found? Where if the image is not found, return a False And if the image is found, return the coordinates of the location found... It can also be automatically clicked.

This function came to mind as a trigger for 'done' when waiting for a specific visual response from a web page that loads. I am created automation for browsing websites in an operation based only on visual, so I should not use libs as requests or selenium. The lib pyautogui was the best tool I found, but its methods are very rudimentary (focus only on the essentials) and I cannot create more practical functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ow boy... I have already suffered from how lean the pyautogui methods are...

Maybe it will help you.

Below there is a very flexible to make continuous and optimized searches in small areas.

I tried to make the docstring as readable as possible.

If the function doesn't seem clear enough to you, please let me know that I will improve the docstring.

```
import logging
import pyautogui as pag
from PIL import Image
import time

def pag_suf(img, x, y, margin, clicks=0, duration=0, interval=0,
            debug_msg='', time_limit=None, sample_dump=None):
    """
    Pyautogui - Search Until Find
    Searches the image indefinitely at a specific point on the screen
    considering as the search area, the image size plus an expansion margin.
    If found, you can click on the center of the image.
    :param img: String. Fullpath image | List. List of Fullpath image
    :param x: coordinate x
    :param y: coordinate y
    :param margin: Integer. expansion margin to expand the search area
    :param clicks: Integer. number of clicks
    :param duration: Float. duration of mouse movement
    :param interval: Float. sleep time after click
    :param time_limit: Integer. Time limit in seconds
    :param debug_msg: String. Debug message to identify log
    :param sample_dump: String. File name if image .bmp
    :return: List. Coordinates of the center of the found image. |
             False. If time_limit reached.
    """

    is_string = type(img) == str
    list_img = []
    if is_string:
        list_img.append(img)
    else:
        list_img = img

    # Search for image at the indicated location with tolerance margins
    return_value = None
    logging.debug(f"{debug_msg}: Finding...")
    first_loop = True
    start_time = time.time()

    while return_value is None:

        # Scape in time_limit
        if time_limit is not None:
            elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
            if elapsed_time > time_limit:
                return False
            else:
                pass
        else:
            pass

        if first_loop is False:
            time.sleep(0.5)
        else:
            first_loop = False

        for img in list_img:
            im = Image.open(img)
            # Defining variables
            img_width, img_height = im.size
            coor_x = x - img_width / 2 - margin
            coor_y = y - img_height / 2 - margin
            region_x = img_width + margin * 2
            region_y = img_height + margin * 2

            # Save collected sample
            screen_sample = pag.screenshot(imageFilename=sample_dump,
                                            region=(coor_x, coor_y,
                                                    region_x, region_y))
            return_value = pag.locate(img, screen_sample)
            if return_value is not None:
                # logging.debug(img)
                break

    logging.debug(f"{debug_msg}: Found.")

    click_x = coor_x + return_value[0] + img_width / 2
    click_y = coor_y + return_value[1] + img_height / 2

    # Click on the center of the found location
    if clicks != 0:
        pag.click(click_x, click_y, clicks,
                  duration=duration, interval=interval)

    click_arr = []
    click_arr.append(click_x)
    click_arr.append(click_y)

    return click_arr
```